# How to add attributes that are not present in the model to the object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a requirement where I would like to add a attribute to the object so as to identify the type it belongs

```
dresses = Cloth.select("id as id and cloth_name as name")
```

and I want to add `cloth_type` along with each resulting object and this cloth_type is not actually present in my model but I need to add this. So how can I do this?

say for example

```
dresses.cloth_type = "jeans"
```

and the result should be something like

```
{"id" : 1, "name" : "dress1", "cloth_type" : "jeans"}
```

I actually tried assign_attributes, write_attributes and update and none seems to work.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added the field to your database through a migration?

Comment: No, I do not want to have a field like that in my model but only needed to assign string dynamically from the controller.

Comment: @Logesh : What's the logic behind adding `cloth_type = 'jeans'`? Does it come from any other association? or is it hardcoded in a Hash/Array in a constant or something? What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: I want to hard code the value to the hash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply add an `attr_accessor` to your model:

```
class Cloth < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :cloth_type
end


c = Cloth.first
c.cloth_type = "whatever"
c.cloth_type # => "whatever"
```

You can also add the attribute to all records (it will not be an attribute in the traditional sense) using the `select` method.

```
clothes = Cloth.select("*, 'whatever' as cloth_type")
clothes.first.cloth_type # => "whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna deal with several types of objects keeping only one table in database (here clothes for objects dresses or many others), you can use [STI](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/). It will allow you to have several objects if u need to implement different behaviors for each.
If you don't, you can just create a migration to add a column named 'cloth_type' in your table and then put this in your class :

```
scope :dresses, -> { where(cloth_type: 'dress') }
```

Then you should be able to access Clothes.dresses.
Or you can just do :

```
dresses = Cloth.where(cloth_type: 'dress')
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't understand well. In this case, the attr_accessor is the way to go. You do not need a field in the database to deal with it and it's doing what you want.

Comment: The one I posted in the question returns an error "undefined method `cloth_type=' for #<Cloth::ActiveRecord_Relation

Comment: @Logesh You're calling the method on a collection of records, not on a single record.

Comment: You can get a single record from a collection through the `each` method

Comment: @ Jiří Pospíšil: Yes, So how can I add to each record without using "each do" as it would cause performance issue if there are large number of records present.